# Gcloud Dataflow workbench instance struck at provisioning state

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using a dataflow workbench instance (similar to vertex ai workbench instance) few months back. Today when I try to start the instance it is completely struck at provisioning state. When I try to create a new instance it is working fine but the existing instance in which I have the ipynb files isn't responding.
[Snapshot of the provisioning stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aTRp.png)

I tried using gcloud cli to start and the result is still the same. I also ensured my cloud resource manager api is enabled.